# Tabular centering

Tags: arrays

How can I position the 1 exactly in the center?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

 \begin{center}
 
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} 
 \hline
$1$ &  $1$ &  $1$ \\
 \hline
 1 & 1 & 1  \\ 
 \hline
 1 & 1 & 1  \\ 
 \hline
 1 & 1 & 1  \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}

  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
1&1&1&1\\ \hline
1&1&1&1\\ \hline
1&1&1&1\\ \hline
1&1&1&1\\ \hline
1&1&1&1\\ \hline
 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you need all these packages?

Comment: just forgot to delete

Comment: `\centering` not `\center`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks

Answer (score 6):

With `tabularray` package, you can simple remove vertical space reserved for letters descents and by this vertical centered letters 1:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{hlines={1pt,teal}, vlines={1pt,teal},
            colspec={*{3}{c}},
            belowsep=0pt
            }
  1 & 1 & 1     \\
  1 & 1 & 1     \\
  1 & 1 & 1     \\
  1 & 1 & 1     \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another solution with `cellspace`: this package defines a minimal vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with  the letter `S` by default, or any letter you please  with the option `column= some letter`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{5pt}

\begin{document}

 \begin{center}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue}
\begin{tabular}{|Sc|Sc|Sc|}
 \hline
$1$ & $1$ & $1$ \\
 \hline
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 \hline
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 \hline
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]