# \cellcolor does not change the cell color when \makegapedcells is used

Tags: arrays

I want to fill the box but `\cellcolor{red}` doesn't work.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}

\begin{document}

\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
\cellcolor{red}1&1&1&1\\ \hline
1&1&1&1\\ \hline
1&1&1&1\\ \hline
1&1&1&1\\ \hline
1&1&1&1\\ \hline
 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well it did raise "Undefined control sequence" for the cellcolor command there... Make sure that your minimal working example is correct, you need to add `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
`. ■ Using https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185674/how-to-see-which-package-define-a-particular-command-macro you can figure out which package the commands belong to (colortbl), and figure out the issue is that makegapedcell conflicts with cellcolor in colortbl.

Comment: Mostly duplicate of [tables - makegapedcells disables rowcolor - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378268/makegapedcells-disables-rowcolor), except the row/cell difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is a kind of solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit=5pt,cell-space-bottom-limit=5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
 \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|c|} 
    \hline
      \cellcolor{red}1& 1 & 1 \\ \hline 
      1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
      1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just load the `colortbl` package – or `xcolor`with option `[table]`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{5pt}

\begin{document}

 \begin{center}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue}
\begin{tabular}{|Sc|Sc|Sc|}
 \hline
\cellcolor{Tomato}$1$ & $1$ & $1$ \\
 \hline
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 \hline
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 \hline
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to do it on my own code, but I installed the package that you said did not work, the situation is the same:( @Bernard

Comment: @Pitaya88: Which package? – colortbl?

Answer (score 3):

In case that you would use [my answer][1] then for coloring od some cell you only need to add the following attribute to this cell:

```
\SetCell{bg=<name of desired color>}
```

because in my answer for coloring of rules is already used `xcolor` package. So your matrix ca be write as:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{hlines={1pt,teal}, vlines={1pt,teal},
            colspec={*{3}{c}},
            belowsep=0pt
            }
\SetCell{bg=red}  1 
    & 1 & 1     \\
  1 & 1 & 1     \\
  1 & 1 & 1     \\
  1 & 1 & 1     \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}

[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625660/tabular-centering/625669#625669
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7q9E.png
```